# Automapper func expression mapping

Tags: expression, automapper

I am using the code shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424501/automapper-for-funcs-between-selector-types) to convert the expression but i get an error "sequence has no elements". My source and destination objects have other objects as well

Source:

```
public class Main  
{
     public int id {get; set;}
     public Sub sub {get; set;}
}
```

Destination:

```
public class MainBo  
{
     public int id {get; set;}
     public SubBo subBo {get; set;}
}
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Consider expanding your question by including the code from the link (which is it, the questions code block or the first answer?) and the stack trace for your error.

Comment: first answer is the what i am using to resolve simple objects i.e. with primitive properties. Now, I have an object that contains another object and i would like to convert the expression for it.