# Mapping Expression<Func<Type1,bool>> Expression<Func<Type2, bool>>

Tags: .net, lambda, automapper, func

I want to pass my query from Business Layer to Service Layer but when doing this i have to convert my DTO to Entity model.

Normally i can convert Type1 to Type2 via Autommaper but now i want to map 
`Expression<Func<Type1,bool>>` to `Expression<Func<Type2, bool>>`

I got error from Automapper

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. 
Mapping types: Expression`1 -> Expression`1
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: How would you implement it? And for starters, what would you expect the outcome of this mapping operation to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just updated my answer to the another question you commented on, which I think addresses this: [AutoMapper for Func's between selector types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424501/automapper-for-funcs-between-selector-types/7425211#7425211)

As for the error you posted above, that appears to be because you tried to map one Expression type to another with AutoMapper, e.g. `Mapper.Map<Expression<Func<Type1,bool>>,  Expression<Func<Type2, bool>>>(exp1, exp2)`. That sort of thing is not supported; AutoMapper is only for mapping between *instances* of different types, not *expressions* that deal with those types.

Anyway, if you read my other answer it may tell you how to achieve what you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but before i saw your answer i found another implementation of ExpressionVisitor and achieved with that. But your answer will help lots of people.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the problem... thanks for the accept!