# Get Generic Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection

I have a Type TDestination with Name, FullName, etc.
The method recieves a generic type TSource

I convert from one to another like this:

```
private static Type ConvertTypes<TSource>()
    {
        var mytype = typeof(TSource);
        var newName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Plugin)).FullName.Split(',')[0].ToString(), mytype .Name);
        var newFullName = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Plugin)).GetType(newName).FullName;
        var TDestination = Type.GetType(newFullName);
        return TDestination;
    }
```

I need to use it in a Generic Method like `Method<T>()`;

I tried some coding but I was unable to convert the Type to it's generic version.

It all begun when I needed to create a method that recieves `Func<TSource, bool>` and this func needs to be mapped to `Func<TDestination, bool>`.

I recieve a Model class and must convert the func to TDestination that is an Entity Framework class.

Until now, no success.

Anyone?

Comment: So your target type has the same class name but it a different namespace or assembly?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, sir. Same name, different namespace and assembly.

Comment: I suggest you just use a config driven mapper to map between type names then, you could remove much of the expensive reflection.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little sample, Maess?

Comment: Use app settings or a custom config to map one type name to another, then you can just get the target type name from the config and call Type.GetType(newFullName);

Comment: That's nice and will relieve some reflection code. Thanks. But I still can't see how to get the generic type from the type itself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Generic type?  Are you talking about an abstract class or some base class?

Comment: When I watch TSource, it shows the full name without quotes. When I watch the TDestination it shows a Type, a whole object, with lots of stuff, Name, Full Name, etc. I don't know how to reffer to this difference. the TSource came from the "generics" signature, and the TDestination is a type I created.

Comment: Have you looked at invoking your `Method<T>()` using reflection? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use existed solution for mapping between types: [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) or [Emit Mapper](http://emitmapper.codeplex.com/). There's also [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/).

Comment: All the solutions I searched on SackOverflow talk about a Mapper.CreateMapExpression method that I simply can't access. Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424501/automapper-for-funcs-between-selector-types