# Easiest way to convert Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> to Func<IQueryable<U>, IOrderedQueryable<U>>

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to convert `Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>` to `Func<IQueryable<U>, IOrderedQueryable<U>>` using **AutoMapper** as follows:

```
MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
   cfg.CreateMap<Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>, Func<IQueryable<U>, IOrderedQueryable<U>>>();
});
config.CreateMapper();
Mapper mapper = new Mapper(config);
var orderableOfU = mapper.Map<Func<IQueryable<U>, IOrderedQueryable<U>>>(orderableOfT);
```

But it does not work! I am getting the following exception:

> System.Func`2[System.Linq.IQueryable`1[TanvirArjel.Application.DTOs.PostDetailsDto],System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[TanvirArjel.Application.DTOs.PostDetailsDto]] needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args. (Parameter 'type')

Here is my Generic type:

```
public class Specification<T> where T : class
{
    public List<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> Conditions { get; set; } = new List<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>();
    public Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>> Includes { get; set; }
    public List<string> IncludeStrings { get; } = new List<string>();
    public Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> OrderBy { get; set; }
    public (string ColumnName, string SortDirection) OrderByDynamic { get; set; }
    public Expression<Func<T, object>> GroupBy { get; set; }
    public int? Skip { get; set; }
    public int? Take { get; set; }
}
```

Actually I am trying to map `Specification<Post>` to `Specification<PostDetailsDto>`.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: What about it does not work?

Comment: It throws exception.

Comment: can you update the question to include the exception details?

Comment: Question has been updated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AutoMapper for Func's between selector types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424501/automapper-for-funcs-between-selector-types)

Comment: @IanKemp No! I have tried this before posting the question. Actually that question and answer is too old for AutoMapper and things are not same in the latest version of the AutoMapper.

Comment: Research AM expression mapping.

Comment: I have read the AM expression mapping documentation but did not find what exactly I need.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu `Expression<Func<>>` is mapping gracefully but not `Func<>`. Could you please help me in this regard?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you will not be able to map one queryable to a queryable of a different type. Even if you can map between those inner types, queryables are a very complex construct that highly depend on the underlying queryable provider. That is not something that AutoMapper would understand and possibly recreate when performing the mapping. And it certainly is not supposed to do that either. – If you want to have queries for `U`, then write your queries for `U` to begin with.

Comment: @poke Thank you for your suggestion but AutoMapper already has Queryable mapping support: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: I don't see how that could possibly work. It's just IL after all. There is some decompiler project that might help, but I don't have a link handy.

Comment: @TanvirArjel The queryable extensions are for *generating* a query based on a defined mapping. This does use the underlying queryable provider to generate it though (think: AutoMapper basically writes the `Select()` expression for you). This does not allow AutoMapper to actually understand how the actual queryable provider works or how to work with that alone. That’s a very different thing.

Comment: @poke Yes! You are correct. Please read my updated question. It may clear my intention more and you may give the more appropriate suggestion.

Comment: https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler