# EF Core 3 not loading related data in second or deeper level

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I'm having a problem loading data from a second level entity using EF Core 3 but it works as expected with EF6 but I'm converting a project to try to migrate the lot to .NET Core, including EF.

I'm not sure if this is the right way to express this but in short, I have a list of companies that have users and these users have roles and for some reason, I can load the companies and their relevant users from a many to many relationship but the roles for each user are not being loaded.

I have the following `Generic` function:

```
protected virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    string includeProperties = null,
    bool isCollection = false,
    int? skip = null,
    int? take = null)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.Context.Set<TEntity>();

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter.Expand());
    }

    if (includeProperties != null)
    {
        query = includeProperties
            .Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        query = orderBy(query);
    }

    if (skip.HasValue)
    {
        query = query.Skip(skip.Value);
    }

    if (take.HasValue)
    {
        query = query.Take(take.Value);
    }

    query = query.AsExpandableEFCore();

    return query;
}
```

and I call it as follows:

```
var databaseCompanies = await this.UnitOfWork.Companies
       .GetAllAsync(null, "Companies.User.Roles");
```

And my entities are defined as follows:

**Company:**

```
public class Company: Entity<Guid>
{
    private ICollection<CompanyUsers> _companyUsers;

    public virtual ICollection<CompanyUsers> CompanyUsers
    {
        get => this._companyUsers ?? (this._companyUsers = new HashSet<CompanyUsers>());
        set => this._companyUsers = value;
    }
}
```

**User:**

```
public class User : Entity<Guid>
{
    private ICollection<CompanyUsers> _companyUsers;
    private ICollection<UserRole> _roles;

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> Roles
    {
        get => this._roles ?? (this._roles = new HashSet<UserRole>());
        set => this._roles = value;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<CompanyUsers> CompanyUsers
    {
        get => this._companyUsers ?? (this._companyUsers = new HashSet<CompanyUsers>());
        set => this._companyUsers = value;
    }
}
```

**Role:**

```
public class UserRole
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public RoleType Role { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

**Class to define the many to many relation:**

```
public class CompanyUsers
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the Company and User classes have a many to many relation defined by CompanyUsers and there is a one to many relationship between the User the the UserRole classes. When calling:

```
var databaseCompanies = await this.UnitOfWork.Companies
       .GetAllAsync(null, "Companies.User");
```

It only loads the companies and the users, so I tried this instead:

```
var databaseCompanies = await this.UnitOfWork.Companies
       .GetAllAsync(null, "Companies.User.Roles");
```

or

```
var databaseCompanies = await this.UnitOfWork.Companies
      .GetAllAsync(null, "Companies.User,Companies.User.Roles");
```

But none of them work and the roles for the users belonging to the companies never get loaded.

In the last example, it will add 2 .Include but when looking at the query variable but I noticed that expression has 2 arguments but they are different of different type:

1) {value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Data.Entities.Company])}
2) "Company.User.Roles"

Again, if I load only one level below the main entity such as load a specific user, it will load its roles accordingly:

```
var databaseUser = await this.UnitOfWork.Users
      .GetFirstAsync(u => u.Username == username, null, "Roles", true);
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned below, I really wish I could swear right now!! The penny dropped after noticing that the query generated by EF Core was correct and returned the role as part of the query but they were all NULL.

I went to check my Roles table and that's when I realized that it had been wiped when I rolled back a migration regarding roles in order to fix the relationship and I never re-generated the dummy roles that were associated with all the users of the companies I had defined!!

Apologies to all of you who helped!!

Comment: May I know how's your final query result look like? I suspect there is problem when you're building `includeProperties`.

Comment: @TaneYoroshi Thanks for offering but I figured it out.. Check updated answer. Feeling really stupid after wasting so much time on it and the penny only dropped after checking SQL Profiler and I noticed that the query generated by EF was correct and included the roles!! Look, it's sorted which is the main thing!

Answer (score 2):

You need to include related data using ThenInclude.

Look at this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

**From link**:

> You can drill down through relationships to include multiple levels of
>   related data using the ThenInclude method. The following example loads
>   all blogs, their related posts, and the author of each post. C#

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
            .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: What you suggested will not work for me as I'm using a generic method and when using the string overloaded method of `Include` as I'm showing above, it does not provide for the `ThenInclude`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `GetQueryable` method parameters replace `string includeProperties = null` with `Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>> includes == null` and then in the method body update the code as follows:

```
if (includes != null)
{
    query = includes(query);
}
```

Now when calling the `GetQueryable` method, pass the value of `includes` as follows:

`sp => sp.Include(i => i.FirstLevel).ThenInclude(f => f.SecondLevel)`

Job done! Now It should work as expected!

Comment: Besides the magic strings, `Include("FirstLevel.SecondLevel")` is the **exact** equivalent of what you wrote. So if this works, then the original should also work and vice versa.

Comment: @IvanStoev wow! I had no idea! Thanks for sharing. By the way, please take a look onto it and give me an idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492563/easiest-way-to-convert-funciqueryablet-iorderedqueryablet-to-funciquerya

Comment: So in short, beside the magic string :), what I have is correct i.e. CompanyUsers.User.Roles and yet it does not work for the last level i.e. Roles.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I wish I could swear right now! Check my updated answer in a few!!!

Comment: @Thierry But passing literal string is not recommended as there is a chance of mistake. So always follow strongly type option as I have shown.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I'll give that a shot and see how I get on but remember that my main problem was self inflicted by having accidentally delete all my user's roles after reverting a migration but if I can improve my code in the process, definite welcome bonus.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Thanks for highlighting this. I was actually doing it for the OrderBy and while it is definitely more strict as I'm now using strongly type, I have to post another question and try to resolve an issue where I'm using the `.Find` as it does not support IIncludableQueryable which is a pain as the following no longer works: `this.Context.Entry(entity).Collection(includes).Load();`